# Is there any type in Python that can't be converted to a string?

Tags: python, type-conversion, string-conversion

Can I convert everything into a string in Python?

For instance, will this ever throw an error?

```py
def test(arg):
    try:
       arg=str(arg)
    except ValueError:
```

Comment: You could write a custom class that throws an error (or fails to return a string) on one or both of `__repr__` and `__str__`, but certainly everything in the standard library and the overwhelming majority of other stuff can be stringified (at the very least as `<... object at 0x...>`, if not something more helpful).

Comment: All type can be  converted in String in python using str.

Answer (score 5):

Every type in the standard library can be converted to a string in Python by using the `str()` function. However, not every object in Python needs to be in the standard library.

For example, instances of following class will throw a `TypeError` when attempting to convert them to a string:

```
class O:
    def __str__(self):
        pass

o = O()
print(str(o))
# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

This happens because we have overridden the default `__str__` method to something that does not return a string.